# stoppropagation event on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, stoppropagation

I have a input filed, calls ajax autocomplete list. Propagation works fine on list First time but on second time list does not get selected, I cannot select the list items second time on click.

Preventing the click so the dropdown does not slide Toggle.

Here is the propagation code.

```
//on click of autocomplete list, do not close panel                
$('.autocomplete, .ui-autocomplete, .ui-menu-item').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

I tried stoppropagation and preventDefault with return false;

Comment: @rnrneverdies Dabre stopPropagation doesn't allow me to click items second time.

Comment: @RayonDabre Dabre stopPropagation doesn't allow me to click items second time.

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see how to ask questions

Answer (score 0):

Without a complete question it is hard to given an answer, but my guess would be that you need to use

```
$(document).on('click', '.autocomplete, .ui-autocomplete, .ui-menu-item',
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
);
```

When dealing with dynamic DOM jquery's click() event will not work. In these cases you need to use the document on click style click event.